# wraping FileInputStream into BufferedInputStream error

Tags: java, class, netbeans, io

so following is the code that I am trying to run. I am only one week old in java, moderators please be a little bit soft.

```
import java.io.*;  // its includes input output packages 
class BufferedInputStream{
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception // main method
{
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/root/Documents/file"));
// In the above line , I created a BufferedInputStream object(in) and whose constructor takes a File Input Stream
// (I think of it like tunnel whose one end is attached to app and one end is attached to file and since this is input stream, data can only flow from file to app)

    System.out.print(in.read());
// on oracle's website where every class has a description of its methods and constructors 
// BufferedInputStream object has a method , read() which return next byte , so in.read() should return the first byte
    in.close();
//and its closes the stream


   } 

}
```

LIST OF ERRORS ENCOUNTERED WHILE COMPILING THIS CODE using terminal with command javac BufferedInputStream.java

```
BufferedInputStream.java:5: error: constructor BufferedInputStream   in class BufferedInputStream cannot be applied to given types;
    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new    FileInputStream("/root/Documents/file"));
                             ^
  required: no arguments
  found: FileInputStream
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  BufferedInputStream.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
      System.out.print(in.read());
                       ^
  symbol:   method read()
  location: variable in of type BufferedInputStream
    BufferedInputStream.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
    in.close();
      ^
  symbol:   method close()
  location: variable in of type BufferedInputStream
    3 errors
```

But with Netbeans IDE the code is working fine and

```
output is 98
// because file has only one character and that is 'b'
```

So , if the code is working it should work in both(netbeans and in terminal) and if code is erroneous than both should print out the same error.
Now whom should I trust , Netbeans IDE or terminal. I am in a great dilemma

Comment: change the name of your class `class BufferedInputStream{`

Answer (score 1):

Your class name is `BufferedInputStream`. This is confusing the compiler as it thinks the class is trying to create an instance of itself and it can't find a constructor that takes a FileInputStream as a parameter.

Change your class name to something else.